# Insert a google chart in to a HTML page. Google Apps Script

Tags: html, charts, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is the question. I´m trying to create an htmloutput with a chart and insert it in a google site. The code works fine but i don´t know how to change the chart data and put data variables instead of. The code is:

code.gs

```
function doGet() {
return HtmlService
  .createTemplateFromFile('index')
  .evaluate();
}

function getData() {
var ss =SpreadsheetApp.openById('1W3YA2jsuJELYsljy96p5-SMHTlqd0WK55h3bEqA2xR4');
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATOS");
var hojanotas = ss.getSheetByName("NOTAS");
var last = sheet.getLastRow();
var datanotas = hojanotas.getDataRange().getValues();
var datas = sheet.getDataRange();
var lastnotas = hojanotas.getLastRow();
var datos = datas.getValues();
var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
var emaile = email.toString();
Logger.log(datos);
Logger.log(emaile);
  for (var i = 0; i < last; i++){
  var alumno = datos[i][0];
  var user = datos[i][3];

  Logger.log(alumno);
  Logger.log(user);


    if(emaile == user){
      for(var j = 2; j< lastnotas; j++){
        var student = datanotas[j][0];
        if(student == alumno){
          var data = hojanotas.getRange(j+1, 1, 1, 11).getValues();
          Logger.log(student);
          Logger.log(data);


     }}}}
var hojasalida = ss.getSheetByName("SALIDA").getRange(3,1,1,11).setValues(data);

     }
```

and index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<body>

<style>.header{background:lightblue}
td{border-top:solid black 2px} .corner{border:0}
td{font-size:12px}
tr{font-size:12px}
div{font-size:24px}</style>
<? var B3 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1W3YA2jsuJELYsljy96p5-SMHTlqd0WK55h3bEqA2xR4').getSheetByName("SALIDA").getRange("B3").getValue();
var C3 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1W3YA2jsuJELYsljy96p5-SMHTlqd0WK55h3bEqA2xR4').getSheetByName("SALIDA").getRange("C3").getValue();
var D3 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1W3YA2jsuJELYsljy96p5-SMHTlqd0WK55h3bEqA2xR4').getSheetByName("SALIDA").getRange("D3").getValue();
var E3 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1W3YA2jsuJELYsljy96p5-SMHTlqd0WK55h3bEqA2xR4').getSheetByName("SALIDA").getRange("E3").getValue();
var F3 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1W3YA2jsuJELYsljy96p5-SMHTlqd0WK55h3bEqA2xR4').getSheetByName("SALIDA").getRange("F3").getValue();
var G3 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1W3YA2jsuJELYsljy96p5-SMHTlqd0WK55h3bEqA2xR4').getSheetByName("SALIDA").getRange("G3").getValue();
var H3 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1W3YA2jsuJELYsljy96p5-SMHTlqd0WK55h3bEqA2xR4').getSheetByName("SALIDA").getRange("H3").getValue();
var I3 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1W3YA2jsuJELYsljy96p5-SMHTlqd0WK55h3bEqA2xR4').getSheetByName("SALIDA").getRange("I3").getValue();
var B33 = parseInt(B3);

?>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Asignatura', 'Anterior', 'Esta semana'],
      ['Matemáticas',  <?=B3?>,     6],
      ['Lengua',  6,     5],
      ['Naturales',  5,       6],
      ['Inglés',  7,      7]
    ]);

    var options = {

      title: 'Notas del Alumno',
      vAxis: {title: 'Asignaturas',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'black'}}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
 </script>

<? var data = SpreadsheetApp
.openById('1W3YA2jsuJELYsljy96p5-SMHTlqd0WK55h3bEqA2xR4')
.getSheetByName("SALIDA")
.getDataRange()
.getValues(); 
var alumno = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1W3YA2jsuJELYsljy96p5-SMHTlqd0WK55h3bEqA2xR4').getSheetByName("SALIDA").getRange("A3").getValue();
?>
<div><?= alumno ?></div>
<table width="600" border="1" align="center">

<caption>
Notas del Alumno
</caption>
<? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
<tr>

  <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
    <td width="80" ><?= data[i][j] ?></td>
  <? } ?>
</tr>
<? } ?>
</table>
</head>



<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

So, in the part of "function DrawChart(){" in the html part and so on, a want to call some variables instead the data. I tried with an scriplet but it doesn´t work. It says: "the axis #0 cannot be a string" or something similiar

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this line has a problem:

```
<div><?= alumno ?></div>
```

What that scriptlet is trying to do is call a function in the `.gs` file named `alumno`.  Plus, if you were trying to call a function named `alumno`, it would need to be like this:

```
<div><?= alumno(); ?></div>
```

If you want to inject the value of the variable `alumno` into that div tag, you need to run some JavaScript when the HTML loads.

```
window.onload=function(){
  console.log("This onload did run");
  if (alumno != "") {
    document.getElementById('idAlumno').textContent = alumno;
  };
};
```

Look at the developer tools in your browser, and open the browser console to see if there are any errors.  There may be an unrelated error that is killing your HTML rendering before it gets to the table.